# How to pause an animation and blink at the same time?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

Hello i am having a container with a content in it.
My content is a text with animation :

```
animation: move 15s linear infinite;
```

my keyframes :

```
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(50px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
 
  50% {
    transform: translate(430px);
    opacity: 1;
    
  }
 
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(50px);
  }
}
```

At the 50% its at the end for the container thats where i want it to pause for a sec or two and blink and after that it can  follow the instructions which i gave  here:

```
(100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(50px);
      })
```

can someone help me with that?

thanks

Comment: animated text is often considered a bad idea, it's always annoying when there is lots of animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple steps in your keyframes to create the blinking effect. If you want the element to stay in place when doing so, just make sure to add the same position (in this case `transform: translate(430px);`.

Is this what you were looking for?

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orangered;
  transform: translate(50px);
  animation: move 5s;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(50px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(430px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  52% { transform: translate(430px); opacity: 0; }
  54% { transform: translate(430px); opacity: 1; }
  56% { transform: translate(430px); opacity: 0; }
  58% { transform: translate(430px); opacity: 1; }
  60% { transform: translate(430px); opacity: 1; }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```